# how to calculate the variance between some observations when each observation is an n*m matrix

Tags: matrices, variance, clustering, data-structure

I have a cluster of 250 observations. each observation is a 4 by 9 matrix. 
4 is number of variable parameters observed and 9 is number of days, observations were collected.

I want to know the variance between 250 observations which are in matrix form. as I ve studied so far, variance is calculated among one dimension variables. 
any suggestion for data in matrix form?

Comment: Well, I tend to use Single Value Decomposition, since you can get a clear picture with lower dimensions, but this is more useful for bigger matrices.

Comment: @LeandroAbib, interesting, I m studying about SVD s now. just to make sure what s going one, when I decompose each of matrices to 3 parts, let say U, V, d. then how these three parts are going to return the variance between initial matrices?

Comment: The diagonal n×n matrix has only the single values, right? The single values are also ordered from biggest to lowest, so you can choose how many of them you will use to "reconstruct the original matrix" with lower dimension, and you can calculate the "energy" that this lower dimensional version have. The following link illustrates it's use for image compression, for example, but you can use for any large data analysis: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/SVD-in-image-compression-View-the-m-n-image-as-a-matrix-The-rank-of-this-matrix_fig1_33427320